# Jquery selecting all classes except one

Tags: jquery

I want to do something like so:

```
$('.anwer_labels').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.anwer_labels').removeClass('active');
   // $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');;
   // $(this).removeClass('active');
})
```

In this line i want to add an exception, so that i wouldnt include `$(this)`:

```
$('.anwer_labels').removeClass('active'); //some code here to not add $(this)
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 9):

[`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) will do it.

```
$('.anwer_labels').not(this).removeClass('active');
```

Comment: what about when I want to grab everything .on('click', '*:not(.class2)', function(){})? <- this code does not seem to work.

Comment: answer to my own comment:
$('body').on('click', '*:not(.class2)', function(){}) <- this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

> Description: Selects all elements that do not match the given
>   selector.

Code:

```
$('.anwer_labels').not(this).removeClass('active');
```